# Compilation Error in my Index View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please how do I resolve this error
[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Qwn.png)

view

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATE_CODE)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATE_NAME)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_NAME)
</td>
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var states = db.STATES.Include(s => s.COUNTRIES);
    return View(states.ToList());
}
```

Comment: We need to see the `states` model.

Comment: Seems you're using `foreach` loop in view to iterate `DisplayFor` bound to viewmodel named `states`. If I guess it right, you're want to send `states` to view but the view expecting `IEnumerable` as its model type, I suggest you provide every relevant parts of view code.